# GCM , Registration ID and handling user login/logout

Tags: android, authentication, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have app that allows user to login with credentials issued by the server, lets say simple login with password and usename.
So user starts the app, enter username and password, server authentificates the user, save this information. (details are really don't play any role in this case).
What I need to implement ?
There some events when my server need to notify user. Lets consider order status changed. If so I need to notify user about this, with notification in the status bar.
I have decided to use GCM for this task.
I read about this, and got some questions.

1. When user gets registration ID from GCM service in android, is it constant or it can be changed. As I understand there is no guarantee that it be always the same. So how can I handle refreshes of this ID. 
   Or if I will not call  `GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(applicationContext).register`it will stay the same until I register new or even if I call register method it can return the same ID. May I save this ID in SharedPreferences for example to use it for a long time ? Or it can be become invalid after some period of time ?
2. The main problem is that I need to handle multiple users on the same device. As far as I know, registration id issued by gcm service it tied to the device and app. So if new user logged out, and logged in with new credentials (new user account) how can I handle this ? I can for example store this ID in my database on the server and use it until user logout from the account inside my app, and after that just remove it from the database, and if user on this device will login with another account registration ID can be used to notify another user ? Will it work ? Or I have missed something.
3. How can I handle user multiple device. My group notifaction key will be some unique data from user account (email,username..). If I understand correctly, I need to get registration ID on all devices where user logins with its my server account and map this to one notification key. Should I handle notification dismiss by myself and than send upstream message to the GCM server in order to notify other user devices that notification has been dismissed ?

Please help with understanding of this service.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have implemented this in one of our app. In this we send the notification to users whenever new listing get added.

User can login from multiple devices same time. Device may be android or iOS anything. 
Also multiple users can login from same device (After logging out previous users).

Whenever user log in from Android device will get the registration ID from GCM. This GCM id is not constant for one device, it gets changed whenever you again request it from GCM server.

We send the notifications to multiple devices using notification key, it contains GCM register ids of all devices. If you lose a notification key, you can’t get it back. To make it worse, You can’t regenerate a new notification key with a previously-used notification key name.
Never use unique data from user account (email, username..) as notification key name. Always generate some random string as notification key name.

To overcome this follow following steps:

1. Create one table to store the following details
   Columns : 
       id
       userId
       deviceGCMId
       deviceId
       notificationKey
       notificationKeyName
2. whenever user logs in sent the following parameters to the server. 
   GCMId, deviceId, userId
3. First check that userId and deviceId exists or not. 
   If not exists then go to step 5 else go to step 6
4. From given userId get the notificationKey and notificationKeyName from table. If not found then generate new notificationKeyName and from that key generate new notificationKey. Use current GCMRegId to generate the key. Store the keys in variables.
5. Add new entry in table with notificationKey and keyname generated in step 4. Also add the GCM id under notification key.
6. Check the deviceId is same and GCM id is different then add update the GCM id in table and add that GCM id under notification key. If device id and GCM id same then no need to do anything

Sometimes notification key get discarded from GCM server and it shows the key not found error. In this case create the new notificationKey from new key name and add GCM ids against that key.

For more info go through following useful links

https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/notifications-d7df385b0ff4

https://medium.com/@Bicx/adventures-in-android-user-notifications-e6568871d9be

Hope this will help

Comment: Can user get previous message till the user is logout? And when logged in user received the messages. Hope I am clear. Thank you

Comment: User won't get the message if logout from application. Because whenever logout action called we removed the device GCM id from notification key.

Comment: Yeah, But if we store the data for the logout user(s) in other storage and when the user login, it check for user's available data and send it to user. This is my Idea.

Comment: @SantoshJagtap at point 6, if the GCM id of the Device is different, i must only add the new GCM id under the notification key or i have also to remove the old one under the notification key (with a remove post)?

Comment: MattC you need to add this new gcm key in notification key